# Function to sort through instance variables in a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance-variables

So, this question relates to classes and functions.

I have a class CountryCatalogue that has a function findMostPopulousContinent. CountryCatalogue has several instance variables; self._name (country name), self._continent (the continent the country is in), self._population(of the country), and self._area (surface area). 
the function findMostPopulousContinent has to search through the instance variables to sort all the countries by their continent, and then add up the population of those countries to find the total population for that continent. Any ideas?

Edit-
So far I am thinking something like this, for each continent;

```
    def findMostPopulousContinent(self):
    for entries in self._name:
        if self._continent == "Asia":
            continentpopulation = sum(self._population)
```

But I don't have much experience with classes using more than one input so I'm not sure if it can be manipulated this way.

Comment: list(sorted(countries, key=lambda country: country._population))[-1]

Comment: Although this isn't really related, does `CountryCatalogue` inherit from some class named `Country` ? What is an `entry` here? Because according to you, `self._name` is  a string...

Comment: Digging through some of your other questions, it seems that is right. But inheritance is an anti-pattern in this case, you should go for composition.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are two different classes in the program, Country and CountryCatalogue. 
I agree this is a stupid way to go about things but unfortunately its the way the assignment has forced us to go. You should read the instructions, they don't make any more sense than the actual layout of the program does.

Comment: @MezyMinzy quite frankly, that is horrifying. Are you certain that you are suppose to use *inheritance* rather than *composition*? Because honestly this is a textbook case of when **not** to use inheritance. A CountryCatalogue is not a Country, so it shouldn't inherit from Country.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It doesn't really say what to use, it just says create a class Country and a class CountryCatalogue, and then later when describing the different functions for CountryCatalogue it several times says, for example the function printCountryCatalogue "print the whole catalogue to the screen, using the default print for the Country Class". I don't think we have even been taught composition, the chapter in the text just covers Inheritance. Unless she wants us to magically learn it ourselves, which wouldn't surprise me in the slightest. So done with this class.

Comment: Composition just that a class contains objects of another class. You *almost certainly have* used composition, but perhaps it was never called that or given a particular name. Probably what your professor meant is that you should be making sure that your printCountryCatalogue function takes advantage of your `Country.printCountry` function. something like `for country in countries: country.printCountry()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How do I go about doing this? Whenever I try and call a function from Country in CountryCatalogue I get an error. For example, "super' object has no attribute 'getPopDensity'", with getPopDensity being a function in Country and a function in CountryCatalogue trying to call getPopDensity(which is the calculation for population density) in order to print a list of all the countries in order of population density. The instructions make it sound like the function in CountryCatalogue is not to do the calculation, so assuming I'm supposed to be calling the function from Country.

Comment: You use `getPopDensity` on an *instance of `Country`* in `CountryCatalogue`. Why are you messing around with `super`? Although I generally don't encourage LPTHW, check out Zed's chapter on [inheritance vs composition](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Awesome thank you! I think I have it pretty much figured out on that side of things. Super was the only thing we were taught to link back to another class (even if it is subclass to class, which I knew but I didn't know anything else). That part of it seems to be working great now.